# Typescript: Is it possible to test if a given type is a generic function type?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

Explicitly, is it possible to create a generic type `IsGenericFunction<T>` so
that

- `IsGenericFunction<<T>(a: T) => T>` resolves to `true`
- `IsGenericFunction<<T,U>(a: T, b: U) => unknown>` resolves to `true` (etc.)
- `IsGenericFunction<(a: number) => string>` resolves to `false` (etc. etc.)
- `IsGenericFunction<X>` resolves to false for any non-function type X

?

My apologies if this is a duplicate, I tried hard to search but there are so many Q&As that boil down to can I figure out the type a generic function was called with (usually at runtime) that I couldn't figure out how to sort through and find out if this more or less unrelated question had been raised and answered.

I can test for being a function type via `T extends (...args: any) => any` but both generic and non-generic function types pass that test. How can I differentiate between the two, if possible?

Comment: I sincerely doubt this is possible; TS doesn't support type-level manipulation of generic function types so there's no "handle" I can even imagine using.  I can't find an authoritative source for that (yet?) so I don't think I'll post an answer.

Comment: When you test for it, you'll probably use it like so, `IsGenericFunction<<T>(a: T) => T>`,  so you see if it's a generic function or not, what's the use case of this utility?

Comment: Well actually I am working on code that accepts a large object all of whose properties are functions, some generic and some not. I don't know which is which. I am trying to provide information (messages) about the functions, using the Parameters<> and ReturnType<> operators. But if I use those directly on the generics, a lot of the types get coerced to `unknown`, losing information and messing up my messages. That's why I'd like to automatically sift the incoming function types into the generic and the non-generic. And @jcalz thanks as always for your quick and authoritative responses!