# Version of ReturnType<> that preserves genericity?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is a variation on [Typescript: Is it possible to test if a given type is a generic function type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933275/typescript-is-it-possible-to-test-if-a-given-type-is-a-generic-function-type) but as it does not necessarily require *distinguishing* generic from non-generic function types, I thought I would ask it separately, even though I fear it will also be impossible:

Is it possible to create a generic type `EnhancedReturnType<F>` such that for generic function types `F` that happen to return functions, `EnhancedReturnType<F>` will produce what F returns as a generic function (to avoid loss of information), and otherwise will produce `ReturnType<F>`. As specific examples,

1. `EnhancedReturnType<<T>(g: (a:T, b:T) => T) => ((a: T) => T)>` should produce `<T>(a:T) => T` (by contrast, `ReturnType<F>` for this type `F` produces `(a: unknown) => unknown` which loses much of the type information of the return type).
2. `EnhancedReturnType<<T>(g: (a:T, b:T) => T) => number>` should produce `number`.
3. `EnhancedReturnType<(g: (a: number, b: string) => number) => ((a: string) => boolean)>` should produce `(a: string) => boolean`
4. I would be perfectly happy for `EnhancedReturnType<<T>(g: (a:T, b:T) => T) => ((a: number) => string)>` to produce `<T>(a:number) => string` or `(a:number) => string` (not sure if those two are the same type or different types...)

The application here is dependency injection: I have a gizmo that takes as input some "functions with dependencies" -- example 1 shows what is meant by this: given g, you get back a function from T to T -- an instance of this type might return, for example,
`(a: T) => g(a, a)`. The gizmo returns what you get by filling in those dependencies in a certain way, i.e. supplying the g's. In the case of a generic "function with dependency", the g it supplies will depend on the parameter type T, so you will really end up with the output of the gizmo being effectively of type `<T>(a: T) => T`. So right now I am stuck trying to type the output of the gizmo... Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Please provide an example of usage. I am not sure I fully understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: There is no purely type-level solution to this.  You can drop down to the value level and use the support for higher order type inference from generic functions, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjp1Mm), but it doesn't generalize so it may or may not be applicable to your use case.

Comment: @jcalz, that playground is so close to what I need -- I just need to perform exactly that operation for the value of every key in a plain object. I [tried this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.2.2#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAMwK4DsIBcCWB7dRABzjxFQjAGcAeYRRAOUTAA8sx0QrEqs4c6AOYAaRPUQBBFu07dEAbwDaAaUSCmAXQBciGOgCeSzQF8xEgEIyOXHsrUbGOvYeNnxDAErW5d1esInXX0DEwA+AAoJBiFdewCtXQiAOlSYXUlVTQBKRABeMMQU1IAjXQss3ILETyyTbLj-R2di5LLECpUc-MLarpNgQfBoeCQIAj5EAAsARjjolDw8XRoAFUjwIjiAW1QoLCT0xFWxMtWqwtX6nqL085uTjwZEEvgki9vtdFRtkrA4D58ATCAbjdCTADWM3yxFI5EoVAis2ywCAA) ...

Comment: ... but It loses type information and the types of the properties in the result come out to just `(...b: any[]) => any`. Any way to salvage this?

Comment: as I said, it doesn't generalize... that's one of the ways it fails (see [ms/TS#49505](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49505))