# Is there a way to "lift" the level of genericity of an object whose values are generic functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is a subsitute question to [Version of ReturnType<> that preserves genericity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321309/version-of-returntype-that-preserves-genericity?noredirect=1#comment136319391_77321309) that was deemed a duplicate. I believe this one is truly distinct, because nowhere am I trying to obtain return values of generic functions.

Instead, suppose I have the type of an object all of whose properties are functions, at least some of which are generic functions with a single parameter(could be all of them if this only works in that case). For example:

```
type Have = {
  foo: <T>(dep: {dependency: (a:T, b:T) => T}) => (a:T) => T
  bar: <T>() => (a: T) => string
}
```

What I would like to do is to produce the generic type with a single parameter, of an object each of whose properties is the type of the corresponding function from the original, instantiated at that parameter. In the example, I am looking to form

```
type Want<T> = {
  foo: (dep: {dependency: (a:T, b:T) => T}) => (a:T) => T
  bar: () => (a: T) => string
}
```

Is there a way of transforming the type `Have` into `Want<T>`? Either as some purely type-level manipulation, or somehow using an object of type Have would be OK, too.

Comment: My apologies for the copy-paste errors; should be fixed now.

Comment: This is not possible at the type level and this is not possible programmatically.  You can use instantiation expressions for each member of `Have`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NVr7ZN) and that's the closest you can get.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So I take it the only way to do this is to know in advance the list of all of the property names of the Have type and explicitly write each one in the source code? That won't work for us, but yes, if that's the answer to the question do feel free to write it up (feel free to be brief) and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TypeScript 5.2, the closest you can get is to drop down to the value level and use one [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) for each member.  It is not possible to use instantiation expressions purely at the type level (see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058192563), the PR implementing instantiation expressions), and therefore it is not possible to do it programmatically over a set of types like the members of an object type.  If you try to do it programmatically such as via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) it will not work (see [microsoft/TypeScript#52035](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52035))

That means this is the best you can do:

```
type Have = {
  foo: <T>(dep: { dependency: (a: T, b: T) => T }) => (a: T) => T
  bar: <T>() => (a: T) => string
}

declare const have: Have;
const wantMaker = <T,>() => ({ foo: have.foo<T>, bar: have.bar<T> });
type Want<T> = ReturnType<typeof wantMaker<T>>;

/* type Want<T> = {
    foo: (dep: {
        dependency: (a: T, b: T) => T;
    }) => (a: T) => T;
    bar: () => (a: T) => string;
} */
```

That's the type you want, but it requires writing a separate expression for each member of `Have`.  If that doesn't meet your needs, then what you want is currently impossible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgN2gXigbwLACgpQGYD2BAXFADwAqAfABQAmEYpaUDkAdg+wMYik1xSFADRQARkICUUZFSgUoAX2myoAqTLkVsuMXABOpSrRVz1801ADOwfQEt2Ac2yLsDbgBsD0bgXY2oAAtECFJ4JABubF9-YCgAdzh2YABZOABrCH0ZchETTTUWQhIgkIA6YuNRPUNSpDKa4yVJKKxQSCgAdSTgJtQAJQhgAFd9dgpwCDJ2iAI8BJ60zP1jKlaAegAqKBmunr70HVx8In42ZiPj47YITlvefkF5ao1VClar5QLzCkt3y-EBn4lh+lhs9icrUUUE262OQA)